# Создание поддомена с помощью .htaccess

Tags: url, .htaccess

как создать поддомен  с помощью .htaccess
нужно превратить

```
http://site.ru/game.php?the=World
```

В

```
http://game.site.ru/World
```

Ну или хотя бы превратить

```
http://site.ru/game.php?the=World
```

В

```
http://site.ru/Game=World
```

как реализовать ?

Answer (score 3):

Вообще то поддомены не создаются, а перенаправляются, т.е. адрес вида `http://game.site.ru/World` обрабатывается htaccess-ом и превращается в `http://site.ru/game.php?the=World` и передаётся скрипту, но урл при этом не затрагивается.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.site/? [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://site/$1.php?the=$2/ [L]
```

p.s.: в DNS поддомены *.site должны указывать на айпи сервера, и в настройках виртуального хоста в апаче должно быть:

```
ServerAlias *.site
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Никак. Поддомены средствами .htaccess не создаются. Перенаправить на поддомен (да куда угодно) - можно, но не создать.

2)

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^the=World$
RewriteRule ^game.php  /Game=World
```

Или, в чуть более общем случае (считаем, что есть только the=XXX):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^the=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^game.php  /Game=%1
```