# Прием поддоменов в htaccess

Tags: php, apache

Делаю автоматические поддомены.

Сейчас мой htaccess выглядит так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([-\w]+)?$ index.php?p1=$1
RewriteRule ^([-\w]+)/([-\w]+)?$ index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2
RewriteRule ^([-\w]+)/([-\w]+)/([-\w]+)?$ index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2&p3=$3
```

Каким кодом я могу также в GET передавать тот параметр, что идет вначале домена в виде поддомена?

```
RewriteRule ^([-\w]+).test.com?$ index.php?p1=$1
```

не открывает сайт

```
Waterfox can’t find the server at a.test.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Переадресация поддоменов с помощью .htaccess

[**Оригинал материала**](https://htmlweb.ru/php/htaccess_subdomain.php)

> Однажды сталкиваешься с проблемой - необходимо иметь неограниченное
>   количество поддоменов, а они как раз кончились. Приходится заниматься
>   изучением mod_rewrite, с помощью которого возможно сделать почти все
>   что угодно.
>
> Потратив достаточно долгое время на поиски готового скрипта, пришлось
>   констатировать тот факт, что либо все это работает не совсем
>   правильно, либо вообще не работает.
>
> Теперь я знаю как это сделать и сейчас покажу на примерах. Для начала
>   сделаем поддомены на свежем сайте, т.е. готовой структуры пока нет и
>   можно делать все что угодно.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.(com|ru)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?(.*)\.domain\.(com|ru)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !sub/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sub/%2/$1
```

- см.возможный дубликат вопроса [Создание поддомена с помощью .htaccess](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/144249/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-htaccess) и [Реализация поддоменов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/168095/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2?rq=1)